# How not init required parameter of a class using swift?

Tags: swift, dart

I want a variable in my class to be optional, but I can't do that without having to pass all variables in the class.

Defining a default value in the variable, it works but I don't know if it's correct.

```swift
var studentOne = Student(name: "Unnamed 1", degree: "test") //it works
var studentTwo = Student(name: "Unnamed 2") //not work, how do i accept this?
studentTwo.printValues()

class Student{
    var name : String?
    var degree : String?
    
    init(name : String, degree: String ) {
        self.name = name
        self.degree = degree
    }

    func printValues(){
        print("name: \(name) and \(degree)")
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is more something like this, which I do using the dart language. In swift how is it done?

```dart
void main() {
  
  var student = Student(name: "Unnamed", degree: "new value");
  var student2 = Student(name: "Only name");
  
  student.printValues();
  student2.printValues();
}

class Student {
  String? name;
  String? degree;
  
  Student({
    this.name,
    this.degree
  });
  
  void printValues(){
    print("Name $name and $degree");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to solve this problem by adding a default value in the constructor. [Example Preview](https://swiftfiddle.com/?c=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32RP2vDMBDFv8pxkw3GIYVSCJRsXTv0z3SLkJRE1DkZ6RwPId%2B9kuUmToaiQdK70%2B%2FdQ2fUuEF37H0QePMDGyXOM6WlOxUjfMhgLAuciQFOKgCro90kOTjeb%2F9EY%2FfBLuVccOykWrY3j33wCuy6usABou12bX6Q9bQt1PIw6eWQK5fishtYQ59w8q26wcbqipvEirCMQDTNUoNiky8FVBPWM2zi5TCxRH7n7Dfnn3MQfnE%2BGVgT3uIQio2SULBaOYHRh59IfOO0d%2FM9%2BHyO%2Fh%2Bfp0JlX7ANHPwIxoMDpbXtBeTg4vZqlmD3ZtjgKf3wc%2FvSrvHyCwE3A6PvAQAA)

```
class Student {
  var name: String?
  var degree: String?

  init(name: String, degree: String? = nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.degree = degree
  }

  func printValues() {
    // handle value by if_let or set optional value
    print("name: \(name) and \(degree)")
  }
}
```

Alternatively, You need to perform constructor overloading in this situation. [Example Preview](https://swiftfiddle.com/?c=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32SwWrDMAyGX0XolEBIaWEMCqO3XXfY1pMuxnZbs1QOsdIcSt99dpy1aWHFF%2FmX9P2S8Rk1rtEdW98JvPuejRLnmeLRjQoBPqU3lgXOxAAn1QGro11HuXO83%2FyJxu47O5dTwrGTYl5ePdSVmQoQbLOrUyW8jfyZmjuinoOUufyDf4qbmnY9a2hjtWxV09tQXJtGsSDMRKIRXYJiky7ZvSQsJ9jIS6uH%2FEAfnNym15rGIvzmFBlYEt6WJxQbJKJgsXACg%2B9%2BAvGNU9%2FN9%2BDzNfgnPqtMZZ%2BxFRz8AMaDA6W1bQXk4MLmahZh92ZY4Sn%2Bh5f6tV7i5RcnuejDHQIAAA%3D%3D)

```
class Student {
  var name: String?
  var degree: String?

  init(name: String, degree: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.degree = degree
  }

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }

  func printValues() {
    // handle value by if_let or set optional value
    print("name: \(name) and \(degree)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the property is optional the default should be `nil`, not `""`.

Comment: Constructor overloading (2nd) is the best solution for handle cases in this situation, because in this the default value is `nil` not `""`.

Comment: In your first example you set the default value for the `degree` parameter in the initializer to be `""` but the default parameter value should be `nil`.

Comment: We only set `nil` at the time of declaration but did not set `nil` at the time of initialization in the constructor because `nil` is not typecast in the `String`.  
`var name: String? = nil` is valid  
but `init(name: String, degree: String = nil)` not valid.  

That's I shared the 2nd example as well to manage this error.

Comment: I also added a comment in the code after your recommendation. Thanks @HangarRash

Comment: Use `init(name: String, degree: String? = nil) {`.

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash for valuable suggestions. I added it according to your suggestions.